# Logo in navbar is resized, but thumbnail for link retains original proportions

Tags: html, css, materialize

I am trying to resize a large image for my logo in a navbar using the Materialize.css framework. The height & width of the logo was reduced to 7% using CSS, which allowed the image to fit inside the navbar.  However, the actual width of the thumbnail (`<a>` tag) is still `1280px`.

How would I reduce the width of the thumbnail to fit proportionally to the corresponding image?  Please see code below - I have also provided a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/mtaggart89/pen/VeKOPW) for this project. Thanks in advance!

HTML:

```
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Bill Test Page</title>
      <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/css/materialize.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>


      <nav>
        <div class="nav-wrapper white">
          <a href="#" class="brand-logo"><img src="http://www.vectortemplates.com/raster/batman/batman-logo-big.gif" id="logo" /></a>
          <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
            <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
            <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>


      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"> </script>
      <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/js/materialize.min.js"> </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS:

```
    #logo {
      height: 7%;
      width: 7%;
      padding: 7px;
    }

    .nav-wrapper #nav-mobile li a {
      color: black;
    }

    .nav-wrapper #nav-mobile li a:hover {
      background: black;
      color: white;
    }
```

Comment: So the image gets resized and you want the `a` tag to get the same width as the one of the image?

Comment: @gsamaras Yes, I would like the `a` tag to be the same width as the image

Comment: @mtaggart I added a new answer that I think will work well for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so if here is a work around using javascript: http://codepen.io/dirtysmith/pen/adBLyd

Change the html to this:

```
      <nav>
        <div class="nav-wrapper white">
          <div id="imgWrapper" class="brand-logo"></div>
          <!--<a href="#" id="hyper" class="brand-logo"></a>-->

          <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
            <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
            <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

Add this javascript:

```
var img = new Image();
var div = document.getElementById('imgWrapper');

img.onload = function() {
  div.appendChild(img);
};

img.src = 'http://www.vectortemplates.com/raster/batman/batman-logo-big.gif';
img.className = "logo";

img.onclick = function() {
    window.location.href = 'http://putyourlocationhere/';
};
```

And then to give the pointer effect add this to the css:

```
.logo {
  width: 7%;
  height: 7%;
  padding: 7px;
  cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want the `a` tag to get the width of the logo, you should do this:

```
$(".brand-logo").css("width", $("#logo").width());
```

which will actually make the `a` tag too small, thus you need to reconsider the size of your logo. If you do:

```
#logo {
   height: 50%;
   width: 50%;
   padding: 7px;
}
```

for example, then you will see it, as one can see in this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skxqymd4/).

Comment: I added this jQuery to the Codepen and I could see the thumbnail, but for some strange reason the actual image disappeared?

Comment: @mtaggart me too, I think it gets too small. See my edit.